# "as opposed to" vs "as supposed to"

Tags: word-choice

My colleague wrote this:

> Outcome of the meeting:
>
> Make rocket-balancer configuration within each app **as supposed to** the auto-configuration library.

I think it should be "as opposed to" or "rather than" instead.

Normally we store the configuration in the "auto-configuration library", but in this case we made a conscious decision to deviate from the common way. So "as supposed to" might still be correct here, even though it changes the meaning of the sentence, isn't it?

Comment: You are correct. Supposed is entirely  wrong. Go to the dictionary to  prove your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was almost certainly meant to be "as opposed to". It is very possible for people to substitute intended words with those that sound similar when speaking. Less so in writing but still possible. Depending on their skills with English they may or may not notice the difference. If the meant to use "supposed to" in some way they would likely have used a different phrase.

Comment: Your point about sounding similar is probably at the root of this silly solecism.

Comment: Do you really think you should be answering questions of this level on a forum for serious students of the English language at the very least?

Comment: @David; I actually think I should be. Though I continue to score from those who agree I am at risk from those who trash my input, and often do.  You should posit your answers opposite mine if you have better.

Comment: I asked about *answering one particular question*, not about your answers in general, about which I neither know or care. The reason is that I find this answer unsuitable for a ["site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts."](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), the Help section on answering questions ["Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here…"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), and the existence of SE English Language Learners. Answering inappropriate questions here only encourages more.